# Extract subset of string in dataframe column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have one of the columns in the data frame as follows. Need to get the output as shown.

```
Data :
NM_001104633|0|Sema3d|-
NM_0011042|0|XYZ|-
NM_0956|0|ghd|+

Required output :
Sema3d
XYZ
ghd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = c("NM_001104633|0|Sema3d|-", "NM_0011042|0|XYZ|-", "NM_0956|0|ghd|+")
sub(".*0\\|(.*)\\|[+|-]", "\\1", x)
#[1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"

#OR
sapply(strsplit(x, "\\|"), function(s) s[3])
#[1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"

#OR
sapply(x, function(s){
    inds = gregexpr("\\|", s)[[1]]
    substring(s, inds[2] + 1, inds[3] - 1)
},
USE.NAMES = FALSE)
#[1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `read.table` to separate them in different columns and then select only the one which we are interested in.

```
read.table(text = df$V1, sep = "|")

#           V1 V2     V3 V4
#1 NM_001104633  0 Sema3d  -
#2   NM_0011042  0    XYZ  -
#3      NM_0956  0    ghd  +
```

We can also use `tidyr::separate` for this

```
tidyr::separate(df, V1, into = paste0("col1", 1:4), sep = "\\|")
```

Or `cSplit` from `splitstackshape`

```
splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "V1", sep = "|")
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("NM_001104633|0|Sema3d|-", "NM_0011042|0|XYZ|-", 
"NM_0956|0|ghd|+")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex takes all text between the last pair of `|` followed by a `+` or a `-`.

`([^\|]*)(?=\|(\+|-))`

[Demo](https://regexr.com/4jkgq)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
sub(".*\\|(\\w+)\\|[-+]$", "\\1", x)
#[1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"
```

---

Or using `gsub`

```
gsub(".*\\d+\\||\\|.*", "", x)
#[1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"
```

#### data

```
x <- c("NM_001104633|0|Sema3d|-", "NM_0011042|0|XYZ|-", "NM_0956|0|ghd|+")
```

Answer (score 0):

The package *unglue* offers a readable alternative, if not as efficient :

```r
x = c("NM_001104633|0|Sema3d|-", "NM_0011042|0|XYZ|-", "NM_0956|0|ghd|+")
unglue::unglue_vec(x, "{drop1}|0|{keep}|{drop2}",var = "keep")
#> [1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"
# or
unglue::unglue_vec(x, "{=.*?}|0|{keep}|{=.*?}")
#> [1] "Sema3d" "XYZ"    "ghd"
```

Or in the data frame directly :

```
df <- data.frame(col = x)
unglue::unglue_unnest(df, col, "{=.*?}|0|{new_col}|{=.*?}")
#>   new_col
#> 1  Sema3d
#> 2     XYZ
#> 3     ghd
```